# Как объединить 3 массива из файлов после цикла foreach?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно объединить несколько массивов в один через функцию array_merge() после цикла foreach? Пишу такую функцию:

```
public function getFilesGenres() {
    $files = scandir(__DIR__.'/genres');
    $config = config('songscrud.genres.langs');

    $array = [];
    foreach($config as $lang) {
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file))
            {
                $path = __DIR__.'/genres/' . $file;
                $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                if ($lang === $ext) {
                    $array[$lang] = require($path);
                    $array = array_merge($array[$lang]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $array;
}
```

Записываю каждый массив в массив с языком типа en, ru, de. В итоге выдаёт только массив из первого файла и ничего не объединяется. Пробовал записывать так:

```
        $array1 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_ru' => 'Народная музыка', 'slug_ru' => 'народная-музыка', 'translit_ru' => 'narodnaja-muzyka'];
        $array2 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_de' => 'Ethnische Musik', 'slug_de' => 'ethnische-musik'];
        $array3 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_en' => 'Ethnic music', 'slug_en' => 'ethnic-music'];

        return array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой код работает хорошо и объединяет всё в один массив. Как объединять массивы динамично через файлы с массивами используя цикл?

Comment: `$tmp = require...` и `$array = array_merge($array, $tmp)`, хотя есть подозрение что тут в целом костыльный код какой-то

Comment: Выводит 2229 записей, данные берутся из 3ёх файлов с языковыми версиями. В каждой по 743 записи. 743 записи должно быть всего и нужно чтобы они выводились как в примере в посте.

Comment: Ну и если в каждой записи у тебя есть ключ `slug_en`, то что в итоговом массиве должно быть? 700 ключей `slug_en`?

Comment: Да всё верно 743 `slug_en`, 743 `slug_de`, 743 `slug_ru` и всё находится в разных файлах, а нужно объединить всё в один массив на 743 записи.

Comment: А логика объединения какая?

Comment: Под регулярку `/\.(php)/` также попадет файл `ololo.php.txt`.

Comment: В папке /genres/ расположены файлы с названиями языков. Пример: ru.php, en.php, de.php

В конфиге будут задаваться параметры какие языки использовать для заливки в БД через консоль.